# Unable to get repr for <class 'weka.classifiers.Classifier'>

Tags: python-2.7, jvm, weka, feature-selection

I keep getting this error whenever I run this program and I am not sure why. I am using the weka Python wrapper and I can't seem to use the documentation to make it work. I am slightly new to this and probably that's why.

```
import weka.core.jvm as jvm

from weka.classifiers import Classifier
from weka.filters import Filter

from classifier.KFoldClassifierExecutor import KFoldClassifierExecutor
from featureselection.FeatureSelection import FeatureSelection

jvm.start(system_cp=True, packages=True)
class DiabetesFeatureSelectionExecution:
    def __init__(self, database, features, runtime, limit, mr):
        self.KFOLD = 10
        self.database = database
        self.features = features
        self.runtime = runtime
        self.mr = mr
        self.classifier = Classifier(classname="weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM")
        self.replaceMissingValues = Filter(classname="weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.ReplaceMissingValues")
        self.executor = KFoldClassifierExecutor(self.classifier)

    def executeAll(self):
        self.executeFullFeaturesWithNoFilters()
        self.executeWithNoFilter()

    def executeWithNoFilter(self):
        print "Inside executeWithNoFilter"
        self.executor.loadFeatures(self.database, self.replaceMissingValues)
        featureSelection = FeatureSelection(self.runtime, self.limit, self.mr, self.executor)
        featureSelection.setExecutor(self.executor)
        featureSelection.execute()

    def executeFullFeaturesWithNoFilters(self):
        print "Inside executeFullFeaturesWithNoFilters"
        self.executor.loadFeatures(self.database, self.replaceMissingValues)
        result = self.executor.execute(self.features, self.KFOLD)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    features = [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
    obj = DiabetesFeatureSelectionExecution("diabetes.arff", features, 200, 6, 0.2)
    obj.executeAll()
    jvm.stop()
```

The error occurs here

```
self.classifier = Classifier(classname="weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM")
```

The error is

```
Unable to get repr for <class 'weka.classifiers.Classifier'>
```

Comment: `KFoldClassifierExecutor` and `FeatureSelection` are not part of the python-weka-wrapper library. Does the stacktrace originate maybe from there?

Comment: No actually, this is the starting point of execution. Those are custom classes I created. The origin is not from there. But for some reason it is unable to find the repr. I followed your video tutorial to install the package but somehow this issue still exist

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace and your code?